# Configure Remote Connection in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, uri

Can anybody help me to configure remote connection in
https://mongolab.com

Like my dbname=demo,dbuser=user,dbpass=pass,localhost
`mongodb://[user:pass@]example.com:localhost/demo`

I have used above string but it gave me error `Invalid URI`.

Can anybody help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Database in mongodb and also create username and password for the database.

mongodb://ds059375.mongolab.com:59375/Name of the remote connection

Thank you